# Update an iphone app without making the user update?

Tags: iphone, ios

quick question...is there a way to make update to an iphone app (news and stuff) without the need of updating the whole app (aka making the user update the app)?

Thanks for any responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app pulls in an RSS / XML feed, then the app itself shouldn't need updating through Apple. Considering your app has a solid foundation and does not bug out.

Also, you can use a `UIWebView` to load a remote html (or php or whatever) file which you can obviously update remotely.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about going through that line as well. So that would be the only two ways (or three technically) to do it right? And thanks!